# Multilanguage page title

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I've created a multilingual drupal page (English as default and german).
On the english page the title works correctly, but on the german page the title is still Drupal (I changed it in the settings and it works in my browser tab header)

How can I make it work?

supermew

Comment: did you try to rebuild the cache ? ( clear cache)

Comment: Are you talking about the sitename? If so, did you try to translate it at `admin/config/system/site-information/translate/de/add`?

Comment: Haha, it was the cache :D

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few pointers which might help:

- If you are talking about the name of your site, then please use the *Admin > Configuration > System > Site information* page to configure it - once in English and once in German.
- If you are talking about a *page* node you created, then:

  - Make sure that you enable translations for the *title* property from [content translation settings](https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/language-content-config.html).
  - Make sure you use the *Translate* tab on the node to input the German title for your page.
- Having done everything above, if you still do not see the German title on the German version of your page, try clearing cache from the *Configuration > Development > Performance* page.

**References:**

- https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/multilingual/translating-content